# install yum on centos minimal machine

Tags: installation, centos7, yum

So far i have used GNOME version of CentOS 7, but for some reason i have to install few packages on my CentOS 7 minimal machine. The first thing i need to install is `yum server` on this machine.

I am unable to find path of Packages.

[image]

What are the commands/steps to install Yum on minimal machine where we just have root login access?

Comment: What does `/mnt/Packages` what do with this? What is the `yum` command you are trying to run?

Comment: I have to install httpd using yum command. Since i have minimal machine and yum server is not installed there. So i am trying to install yum server.